# Lift and projection method in Least Squares Inverse Eigenvalue Problems

Tags: matrix, matlab

I need to implement the *lift and projection* method proposed by `XUZHOU CHEN AND MOODY T. CHU` in http://www4.ncsu.edu/~mtchu/Research/Papers/lsiep.pdf on page 7 in Matlab.

It has been a few days I am trying to do this but I failed, I am not studying Mathematics and Linear Algebra and I saw most of the concepts in that paper for the first time, but for some reasons I have to implement this.

I would be appreciated if any of you can help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about **Matlab** and not  ***Mathematica***.

Comment: @Karsten7. where can I ask questions about Matlab? Because here is a Matlab tag I asked it in here

Comment: Did you read the tag wiki? You may want to ask this question at http://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

I also voted to close. Thought I'd show anyway how one might go about this as an optimization problem using Mathematica.

We set up an example using a symmetric 6x6 matrix and four others we'll use to try to approximate the original. We only are given the eigenvalues of the original.

```
SeedRandom[1111];
mat = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {6, 6}];
symmat = mat + Transpose[mat];
evals = Sort[Eigenvalues[symmat]];
n = 4;
mats = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {n, 6, 6}];
symmats = Map[# + Transpose[#] &, mats];
params = Array[d, 4];
newmat = Apply[Plus, MapThread[Times, {params, symmats}]];
```

Our objective function will minimize the sum of squares of sorted eigenvalues.

```
obj[mults : {_?NumberQ ..}] := Module[
  {nummat = newmat /. Thread[params -> mults], evaldiffs},
  evaldiffs = evals - Sort[Eigenvalues[nummat]];
  evaldiffs.evaldiffs
  ]

{min, vals} = FindMinimum[obj[Array[e, n]], Array[e, n]]

During evaluation of In[248]:= FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>

(* Out[248]= {19.5675013322, {e[1] -> 1.00679569409, 
  e[2] -> 0.338737405044, e[3] -> -0.044044919321, 
  e[4] -> 0.842108515348}} *)
```

Not too bad. Compare eigenvalues:

```
evals

(* Out[254]= {-39.221620442, -36.4856056857, -10.111008584, \
10.5876787783, 14.3454360419, 22.3985005544} *)

Sort[
 Eigenvalues[newmat /. Thread[params -> (Array[e, n] /. vals)]]]

(* Out[250]= {-38.7069641057, -33.9281784835, -9.75078267892, \
12.0789742415, 15.1806417502, 25.5147327114} *)
```

In this case I believe the ordering is the same. In general the matrix approximation would need to account for the permutations of each set of eigenvalues required in order to get the sorted versions (not sorting makes the optimization more difficult, ergo a decrease in quality of the result).